# If the events $x$ and $y$ are independent, and also $x $ and $z$ are independent, is it true that $x$ and $y − z$ are independent?

Tags: probability, independence

If the events $x$ and $y$ are independent, and the events $x $ and $z$ are independent, is it true that the events $x$ and $y − z$ are independent? Prove, or give a counterexample.

Since y-z is just a subset of y, would it be reasonable to assume that x and y-z are independent?

Also, what would happen if y=z?

Comment: If y = z then $y \setminus z$ is the empty set, which you can show is independent of any other set.

Comment: "Since y-z is just a subset of y, would it be reasonable to assume that x and y-z are independent?" Bizarrely, one finds this mistake rather often. If the reasoning was true, since every x and Omega (the full probability space) are independent and every y is "just a subset" of Omega, one would get that x and y are independent, *for every events x and y*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

counterexample

$x$ and $y$ independent, $x$ and $z$ independent, $x$ and $y - z$ not independent.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why it is not independent? Would be not just be left with the region of y?

Comment: $P(x) = 0.5$ but $P(x | y - z) = 0$. Hence the two events are dependent.